# How do I add navigation menu and drawer on top left side top of my Mapbox layer

Tags: java, android, mapbox

[image]I would like to add a navigation menu and drawer on top of my 'MapboX map' layer. 
I have added my 'RelativeLayout' below, See the attached image too. 
Could someone help me to achieve on how to add the menu and Navigation drawer on top of the Map layer.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.mycompany.myfirstglapp.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:text="Hello mate!"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button android:id="@+id/locate1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:onClick="myButton"
    android:text="@string/locate_me"
    android:background="#1880c9"/>


<com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    mapbox:style_url="@string/style_mapbox_streets"
    mapbox:center_latitude="-36.91044"
    mapbox:center_longitude="174.88203"
    mapbox:zoom="12"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to walk you through this the best I can, there are many tutorials out there explaining how to add navigation drawers to an app, you can even start an Android project with one included in the app. For these reasons, I wont go into details on how to add the navigation drawer itself. If you don't want a toolbar (most apps use toolbars though) and instead want to just have the drawer button displayed on top of the map, you'll want to use a `ImageButton` and have an onClick event which will open the drawer when the event occurs. Since you are using a Relative layout, the xml might look like this:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/drawer_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/<your button image>"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
```

Hope this helps you get started.